# Click elements and change boolean value at certain positions in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, boolean

I am using a for loop to draw multiple elements to the screen which are acting as buttons. These are read from a database and drawn as "on" or "off", depending on whether the array entry is `true` or `false`, and the results are also pushed into a new, empty array. This part is all working okay. 
I'm having a bit of trouble keeping track of these elements once they've been drawn, though.

The goal is to be able to click each element on/off, and on each toggle, it also changes the corresponding boolean in the array. For example, the array `[true, false, false, true]` is looped through, and elements are drawn either green/true, or red/false. This will show four squares horizontally, in the order of green, red, red, green. When the first box is clicked, it changes to red (via toggling a class), and the entry at `arr[0][0]` is changed to false (row zero, switch 0).

Is there a way to check which element was clicked in relation to its position in the array, without using a lot of `if` statements? Each element has a unique number, and each row of elements in given a unique name also. I have thought about trying `.click(function(){if (arr[x][y]=true){arr[x][y]=false}else{...});` for every switch drawn, but these seems like a horrendously inefficient way to do it - especially if I want to expand these to many rows and switches. I'm probably missing something blindingly obvious...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .page-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 700px;
        height: 700px;
        background-color: #FFFC88;
    }
    .row {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #FFEECC;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .switch {
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        float: left;
    }
    .active-switch {    
        background-color: #42f480;  
    }
    .unactive-switch {
        background-color: #f44141;  
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-container">
        <div class="main-container"></div>   
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>        
        var store = [{"pattern": [true, false, false, true]}, //pseudodata from database
                     {"pattern": [false, true, false, false]}]; 
        var temp = []; //temp boolean data to be altered in real time
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            var $newRow = $('<div class="row" id="row' + i + '">');
            $('.page-container').append($newRow);
                for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                var $switchOn = $('<div id="switch' + j + '" class="switch active-switch">');
                var $switchOff = $('<div id="switch' + j + '" class="switch unactive-switch">');
                temp[i] = temp[i] || [];
                    if (store[i].pattern[j] === true){
                        $('#row' + [i]).append($switchOn);
                        temp[i].push(true);
                    } else {
                        $('#row' + [i]).append($switchOff);
                        temp[i].push(false);
                    }
                }
        };
        $(".switch").click(function() {
          $(this).toggleClass("active-switch unactive-switch");
          //something here to alter the boolean at temp[x][y]
          console.log(temp[0]); //print altered array in console
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Is there a way to check which element was clicked" yes. You can use the eventArg passed to the click function handler like eventArg.target or use `this` in the event handler, which will reference the element

Comment: I can use `this`, so if I click switch3 on row2, I can toggle a class. The trouble I'm having is the link between `this` and knowing what position in the array `this` should alter. So if I clicked the fourth switch `this` could set `arr[0][3]` to `true` or `false`. However, `arr[0][3]` seems way too static, and I'd have to end up writing so many different variations?

Comment: You should store the index as a `data-` attribute onto the element: `<div ... data-index="' + index + '">`. When an element is clicked you can get it using `$(this).data("index")`. You can event store multiple data attributes, one for `i` called `data-i` and one for `j` called `data-j` and then retrieve them using `.data("i")` and `.data("j")`, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jquery's [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to find index of element in a row.

Similarly, you can find row index using `$(this).parent().index()`.

For example:

```
x=$(this).parent().index()-1; // -1 for adjustment
y=$(this).index();
temp[x][y] = !temp[x][y];
console.log(temp[x]); //print altered array in console
```

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I was looking for. The golden word `index` ! I just quickly tried it quickly with `temp[0][index]` and it's outputting exactly what I needed.